# How to retrieve page speed score from PageSpeed API?

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I am trying to retrieve the PageSpeed score for the website that I am analyzing. I managed to fetch from the API successfully, but I am not able to get the Score from the API.

I found out that the score is in lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score . I tried to fetch that and I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'categories').
```

Here is my code how I fetch the API:

```
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://aviokarte.me&key=mykey')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => console.log(data.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score));
```

I don't know what I do wrong?

When I try to do `console.log(data)` it works and gives me the whole JSON back.

Comment: Try it with the following change: `.then(response => response.json())`. Your problem resolves from the format you retrieves the response data. `response.text()` returns the data as a simple string. `response.json()` returns the data as a Object.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.text()` returns the data as a simple string. `response.json()` returns the data as an Object.

You can read more on this topic here: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/confused-about-json-vs-text

So in my case, I had to use `response.json()`